# How to read the values from a glm::mat4

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, glm-math

I have a glm::mat4 matrix and I need to get the values into a double[16] array. Any ideas on how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
glm::mat4 pMat4;  // your matrix

double dArray[16] = {0.0};

const float *pSource = (const float*)glm::value_ptr(pMat4);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    dArray[i] = pSource[i];
```

Comment: Is it unsafe to use pSource directly?

Comment: Remember to include "#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>"

Comment: Is there a safe way to do this in reverse (getting `float[16]` into a `mat4`)?

Comment: @MattReyer I believe you can use `glm::make_mat4x4()`. Check [this](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00158.html#gaa287485a3978d319e60a1cadd8a1c139) out.

Answer (score 0):

`&mat[0][0]` also will work. From the *OpenGL Interoperability* section in glm [documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00001.html):

```
glm::vec4 v(0.0f);
glm::mat4 m(1.0f);
...
glUniform3fv(uniVec, 1, glm::value_ptr(&v[0]));
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniMat, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0][0]);
```